# logstash : Mutate { gsub ... } not working

Tags: logstash

```
    mutate {
        add_field => {"eee" => "2016 uaie"}
        gsub => [
            "eee", "2016", "2015"
        ]
   }
```

This will indeed create a field "eee", but gsub will **not** update it. Why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

add_field runs when the underlying filter succeeds.  In your case, the mutate{} is being run and then the add_field is run.

To have the mutate{} after the field is added, use two mutate blocks:

```
mutate {
    add_field => {"eee" => "2016 uaie"}
}

mutate {
    gsub => [
        "eee", "2016", "2015"
    ]
}
```